# How to use java repl plugin in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to install [Java REPL plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7215?pr=) for IntelliJ IDEA but it is not working with the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

[image: screenshot of error]

Can anyone tell me how to correct these issues with Java REPL on IntelliJ?

Answer (score 9):

The plugin is broken and will not run on [IntelliJ 14.1.x](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl/issues/87), [15x](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl/issues/87#issuecomment-163522357) or [2016](https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl/issues/97).

As an alternate, you could download the jar executable and run it at a command prompt.
Use the 'Latest Version' link (or compile the source) from here: https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl

```
$ java -jar javarepl.jar
Welcome to JavaREPL version 303 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_65)
Type expression to evaluate, :help for more options or press tab to auto-complete.
java>
```

Comment: Dude i was asking about how to use javarepl plugin in intellij but you are answering about how to run it in cmd,

Comment: FWIW, I installed the plugin and got ClassDefNotFound for a different class. IntelliJ 2015 ultimate. The plugin is broken, the command line version is not.

Answer (score 0):

Still you have the option to run it manually inside Intellij's terminal window, you can add as dependency through maven through libraries section inside project structure or download manually from http://mvnrepository.com:

[image]

Then execute the following inside intellij terminal:

```
$ java -jar javarepl-SOME_VERSION.jar
```

[image]

It usually gives exceptions when used as plugin inside intellij, currently I'm using the same [Java REPL](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html) but online that I hope it might be helpful for you too